# Partial Differential Equations, Fritz John's Global Holmgren Theorem, Schrondinger's Equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need to do next problem, but I don't know how...

Suppose that $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{1+d})$ satisfied **$u_t=v \Delta u$** with $v\in \mathbb{C}\setminus0 $.

Using **Fritz John's Global Holmgren Theorem** prove that if $t_1<t_2$ and $u$ vanishes on a neighborhood of $]t_1,t_2[ \times {x}$, then $u$ vanishes identically on $]t_1,t_2[ \times \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Same as your other question : what is the Fourier transform of $\partial_t u$ (in term of $\widehat{u}$) ?

Comment: Did you mean this $F(\partial_{x_j} f) = i y_j F(f) = i y_j \widehat{f(y)}$ ?

Comment: Then the heat equation becomes $i y_t \widehat{u} = -v (\sum_{n=1}^d y_{x_n}) \widehat{u}$ on the Fourier side. Solving when $\widehat{u}|_{y_t=0} = 1$ and taking the inverse Fourier transform is how we obtain the [heat kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel).